# In EKEventViewController Edit button in two place with same functionality

Tags: ios, iphone

Both Edit button is behaving in same manner. So I want to remove one edit button . How can i achieve  it?

```
//*****my code is here:  
    var eventDetail = EKEventViewController()  
    eventDetail.event = selectedEvent  
    eventDetail.allowsEditing = true  
    eventDetail.allowsCalendarPreview = true 
    eventDetail.delegate = self  
    var navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:eventDetail)  presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by removing it twice:

```
presentViewController(navController, animated: true) {
    eventDetail.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
}
```

/////////////////

```
class EventViewController: EKEventViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    }
}
```